# Accordion with bootstrap and Spservices

Tags: jquery, spservices, boot-strap

I am trying to use this,

It is the best accordion i could find that uses lists. 
I get the main part to work but the pagination is corrupt.

It looks like this. 
[image]

The code comes from the page below.

http://michaelsoriano.com/sharepoint-bootstrap-using-spservices-and-jquery/

If someone has used this and know why the bootstrap will not work, please help.
I have added links to read glyph,flat icons and the bootstrap css. Could it be that the functions used here is different in newer versions of bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is because your customized style(bootstrap) is mixing with the sharepoint page (.aspx) in wich you are trying to insert your

If you have to use a webpart I suggest using "Page Viewer WebPart" instead of "Content Editor".

Content editor is like insert your customized code inside the sharepoint page. "Page Viewer web part" use an iframe , in this way you can separate styles in sharepoint page and your customized styles(bootstrap).